# interpolation between Bochner spaces involving $H^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, interpolation, bochner-spaces

I am reading a paper in which they say that:
Since $u_n$ is bounded in $L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ and due to the strong convergence of $u_n$ in $L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ we conclude with an interpolation argument that
$$u_n\to u\mbox{ in }L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)).$$
Here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary.
So I really do not know that interpolation argument they meant, because I did not see interpolation involving the dual space before. Does anyone know this argument or know any reference about this?
Besides, I have a further question, if I have a sequence $f_n$ which is strong convergent in $L^{8/7}(0,T;W^{-1,4}(\Omega))$ and is bounded in $L^{\infty}(0,\infty;L^2(\Omega))$ and is bounded in $L^2(0,\infty;H_0^1(\Omega))$, may I conclude with a similar argument that $$f_n\to f\mbox{ in }L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)).$$
Here $W^{-1,4}(\Omega)$ is the dual space of $W_0^{1,4}(\Omega)$.

Comment: there should be an inequality of the type $\|u\|_{1} \le C\|u\|_{-1}^\alpha \|u\|_2^{1-\alpha}$ (subscript k means the $H^k$ norm) for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. I don’t know the details on bounded domains but this type of inequality is called an interpolation inequality since if you belong in the endpoint spaces then it shows you belong in the intermediate space (the inequality should be true replacing 1 on the left with any number between -1 and 2) And the Bochner part is unimportant.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, could you give me some source of this kind of interpolation inequality? Because all the interpolation inequality I found does not have a $\lVert u\rVert_{-1}$ term.

Comment: Sorry I am on public transit atm. But the answer below looks good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not about dual spaces, it is just that the interpolation of Sobolev spaces gives Sobolev spaces. If $\Omega$ is a $C^\infty$ bounded set, then
$$
H^s(\Omega) = [H^{-1}(\Omega),H^2(\Omega)]_{\theta}
$$
if $\theta = \frac{s+1}{3}$ (see e.g. Triebel, *Theory of Function Spaces*, Theorem in Sec. 3.3.6, together with the fact that $F^s_{2,2}(\Omega)  = B^s_{2,2}(\Omega) = H^s(\Omega)$). Taking $s=1$, it yields
$$
\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C\,\|u\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}^{1/3}\,\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}^{2/3}.
$$
(Of course, this can also be proved more directly, if $\Omega=\Bbb R^d$, then this comes easily from the Fourier characterization of $H^s$). Hence, taking the $L^2$ norm in time, using Hölder's inequality and replacing $u$ by $u-u_n$,
$$
\|u_n-u\|_{L^2_tH^1(\Omega)} \leq C\,\|u_n-u\|_{L^2_tH^{-1}(\Omega)}^{1/3}\,\|u_n-u\|_{L^2_tH^2(\Omega)}^{2/3}.
$$

---

Your new question is more delicate, but it indeed also works! By interpolation of $L^2_tH^1_0(\Omega)$ and $L^{8/7}_tW^{-1,4}(\Omega)$, you can get convergence in $L^{16/11}_tL^{8/3}(\Omega)$ (since $11/16 = 1/2(1/2+7/8)$ and $3/8 = 1/2(1/4+1/2)$). Since $\Omega$ is bounded, it implies convergence in $L^{16/11}_tL^{2}(\Omega)$. Combining that with  boundedness in $L^\infty_tL^{2}(\Omega)$, it implies convergence in $L^2_tL^{2}(\Omega)$. More precisely
$$\begin{align}
\|u\|_{L^2_tL^{2}(\Omega)} &\leq C\, \|u\|_{L^{16/11}_tL^{2}(\Omega)}^{8/11}\|u\|_{L^\infty_tL^{2}(\Omega)}^{3/11}
\\
&\leq C\, \|u\|_{L^{8/7}_tW^{-1,4}(\Omega)}^{4/11} \|u\|_{L^2_tH^1(\Omega)}^{4/11} \|u\|_{L^\infty_tL^{2}(\Omega)}^{3/11}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Amazing! Really a nice proof! Thank you very much!